# How to enable "Show user agent shadow DOM" in Chrome using a command-line switch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, polymer, chromium

I'm using chai-webdriver to test some Google Polymer components and whenever webdriver loads the Chrome browser it uses a default set of switches. In order for Polymer's Shadow DOM components to appear in the DOM tree, it seems I need to enable the "Show user agent shadow DOM" option in the dev tools, but this gets reset back to disabled every time selenium-webdriver loads Chrome. I could add this to the default switches in webdriver, but I can't find a switch for it in [this list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). Anyone know what the right command-line switch to use is?

Comment: User created Shadow DOM (that created by component built using Polymer) is viewable by default in the DevTools. The "Show user agent shadow DOM" is only for the native elements like `<video>`, `<input type="calendar">`, etc.

Comment: @ebidel Thanks. Apparently then webdriver still can't see user-created shadow dom. Bummer.