# What does Shadow DOM let us achieve?

Tags: html, angular, web-component, shadow-dom

I think shadow DOM lets us achieve style encapsulation and also hiding HTML implementation of the component.

But when I inspect shadow root in chrome I can see the HTML of the component. 
[image]

So what exactly does it help us to achieve? Is it only style encapsulation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help understand Shadow DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656667/need-help-understand-shadow-dom)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452347/shadow-dom-aim-of-using-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, the DevTools allow you to investigate the shadow DOM but if you get the HTML for `index.html` `querySelector('body').innerHTML` the shadow DOM of the elements is not included.

You explicitly need to switch to the shadow DOM of a custom element to get access to that HTML.

Shadow DOM is not about hiding your elements implementation from other developers, it's about hiding it from CSS, JS or other means that might accidentally read or manipulate it.

This allows to break down complexity of the DOM of a whole application to smaller parts that are better manageable.

Comment: `Chrome Dev Tools > Settings > Preferences > Elements > Show user agent shadow DOM` (check)

Comment: User created Shadow DOM (that created by component built using Polymer) is viewable by default in the DevTools. The "Show user agent shadow DOM" is only for the native elements like <video>, <input type="calendar">, etc. (see comment to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26126587/217408)